Footnotes causing errant match using regex in Python
I'm parsing text in Python using regex that typically looks like some version of this:
JT Meta Platforms, Inc. - Class A
Common Stock (META) [ST]S (partial) 02/08/2024 03/05/2024 $1,001 - $15,000
F S: New
S O: Morgan Stanley - Select UMA Account # 1
JT Microsoft Corporation - Common
Stock (MSFT) [ST]S (partial) 02/08/2024 03/05/2024 $1,001 - $15,000
F S: New
S O: Morgan Stanley - Select UMA Account # 1
JT Microsoft Corporation - Common
Stock (MSFT) [OP]P 02/13/2024 03/05/2024 $500,001 -
$1,000,000
F S: New
S O: Morgan Stanley - Portfolio Management Active Assets Account
D: Call options; Strike price $170; Expires 01/17 /2025
C: Ref: 044Q34N6

I've set up a regex to extract 'ticker' (eg, MSFT, META) that looks like this:
r"\(([A-Z]+\.?[A-Z]*?)\)"

This pulls capitalized adjacent chars (eg, IBM, T) sitting within parens, and also allows there to be an optional period (happens occasionally eg, BRK.B) for certain situations.
The below example is matching starting with the '(BM)' characters, which are included in a footnote for a previous transaction, and not valid tickers.  The logic to identify these would be that they're preceded by the 'F S:' footnote designation, where there can be slight deviations in spaces but will include always include 'FS:'.
How to exclude these errant situations using regex in Python?
Alibaba Group Holding Limited
American Depositary Shares each
representing eight Ordinary share
(BABA) [ST]S 01/19/2024 01/22/2024 $1,001 - $15,000
F S: New
S O: Iron Gate GA Brokerage Portfolio > IGGA IRA (BM)
Alphabet Inc. - Class C Capital Stock
(GOOG) [ST]S 01/19/2024 01/22/2024 $1,001 - $15,000
F S: New
S O: Iron Gate GA Brokerage Portfolio > IGGA ROTH IRA (JM)
Alphabet Inc. - Class C Capital Stock
(GOOG) [ST]S 01/19/2024 01/22/2024 $15,001 -
$50,000
F S: New
S O: Iron Gate GA Brokerage Portfolio > IGGA IRA (BM)
Amazon.com, Inc. (AMZN) [ST] S 01/19/2024 01/22/2024 $15,001 -
$50,000
F S: New
S O: Iron Gate GA Brokerage Portfolio > IGGA IRA (BM)
Amazon.com, Inc. (AMZN) [ST] S 01/19/2024 01/22/2024 $1,001 - $15,000
F S: New
S O: Iron Gate GA Brokerage Portfolio > IGGA ROTH IRA (JM)
Amazon.com, Inc. (AMZN) [ST] S 01/19/2024 01/22/2024 $1,001 - $15,000
F S: New
S O: Iron Gate GA Brokerage Portfolio > IGGA ROTH IRA (BM)Filing ID #20024354


Now you have two problems

Just don't search on lines starting with F S: or S O:?

Since you expect only single matches per line, you can use
^(?![A-Z] [A-Z]:).*\(([A-Z]+\.?[A-Z]*)\)

See the regex demo.
Details:

^ - start of string
(?![A-Z] [A-Z]:) - exclude the string that starts with an uppercase letter + space + uppercase letter + :
.* - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
\( - a ( char
([A-Z]+\.?[A-Z]*) - Group 1: one or more uppercase letters, an optional dot and then zero or more uppercase letters
\) - a ) char.

